# Make [delegates] a synonym of [delegation]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

They appear to both refer to the [Delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) which is a design pattern that consists of helper objects that hold methods called on by main objects for example.

Therefore I am suggesting [delegates](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delegates) to be made a synonym of [delegation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delegation) because the latter is the canonical name of the pattern. I am not eligible to propose the synonym myself so perhaps one of the [site moderators](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) could create the synonym.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a bit concerned about doing this without some manual review and cleanup first. Are there any cases where the tag is used about delegation outside of the design pattern?

Comment: I think one can find cases for the usage of *both* tags outside of this specific OO design pattern, and I don' t think we have chance to educate the community to restrict their usage of these tags to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Though I think I will support this, I am not 100% convinced of this suggestion, since "delegates" is also the name of a specific C# syntax for higher order functions, and the tag is often (but not always) used for questions around this.

Neverthless, here is the link where anyone with more than 2.5K rep can vote for or against this:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/delegates/synonyms